# TeamCity "Retry on Fail" Build Trigger - Limit retries

Tags: teamcity

I have a build that I know will fail randomly, around 5% of the time. This is due to an external resource that I have no control over.

Setting a "Retry on Fail" build trigger is easy enough, except that it doesn't allow me to specify a number of retries before it stops trying all together.

Is there a way to have TeamCity retry a build on fail, only *n* number of times?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a larger number for delay between retries (15minutes?) + add notification about build failure. This way you won't miss failure and won't spoil your build history with tons of failed builds.

Or, you can write a [custom trigger plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/teamcity/custom-build-trigger.html) for TeamCity :)

Answer (score 10):

This feature was finally added in version 7.1, See

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-5165

and

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/What%27s+New+in+TeamCity+7.1